# Chern classes, vanishing of smooth sections or vanishing of holomorphic?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, vector-bundles, chern-classes

I have seen both definitions and this is getting me more and more confused.

Are Chern classes dual to the degeneracy cycles of smooth sections or holomorphic?

They can't be the same thing, can they?

Comment: I believe you mean smooth sections rather than dual sections.

Comment: Chern classes of a smooth complex vector bundle on a smooth manifold can be described in terms of cycles where generic sections vanish or are linearly dependent. In particular in the special case of a holomorphic bundle (on a complex manifold) this is true, if there are enough sections.